# CouchDB: Making attachments publicly available from a secure database?

Tags: couchdb, attachment

I have a CouchDB that receives documents of type_ survey. Each survey comes with a jpg attachment.

Is it possible to make this attachment publicly available, despite the database that the survey documents are in not being publicly available? (We wouldn't want to make the surveys themselves publicly accessible)

I'm hoping I might be able to do this from a design document. Or, alternatively, via a redirect or something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. An attachment has to share the same permissions as the doc